# How to convert static_rnn inputs to dynamic_rnn inputs in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

I'm having trouble understanding the input parameter for tensorflow's `dynamic_rnn`. It'd help a lot if I could understand how to convert `static_rnn` inputs to `dynamic_rnn` inputs.

For a `static_rnn`, the input is supposed to be a length `T` list of tensors whose shapes are `[batch_size, input_size]`, where `T` is the sequence length. This makes sense to me.

For a `dynamic_rnn`, the input is supposed to be a Tensor of shape `[batch_size, max_time, ...]`. I don't understand how to incorporate `input_size` here. More generally, I don't know what else you could put in the ellipsis.

Say, for example, that my data consists of 50-character-long sentences, so the `input_size` is the number of letters in the alphabet. For a `static_rnn`, I'd make a length 50 list of tensors whose shapes are `[batch_size, input_size]`. How do I convert this list of tensors to a single tensor, so that I can feed it to a `dynamic_rnn`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `dynamic_rnn` input should be of shape `[batch_size, sequence_length, input_size]`.

Basically the tensor represents `batch_size` examples of length `sequence_length`, and whatever is left in the ellipsis is the shape of a single sequence element.

The thing is, with `dynamic_rnn` you don't need to know sequence_length beforehand, so your input placeholder could look like

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=(batch_size, None, input_size))
```

Which comes in pretty handy. Furthermore, examples in a single batch can have different lengths (but must be padded to the same length), but you must pass the `sequence_length` parameter to `dynamic_rnn` so it knows when to stop calculations for each example.